# Getting a distinct value in result in log analytics KQL

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-log-analytics, kql

I want to get distinct columns for certain rows from my query but also want to return other columns so I want to combine distinct and project but use distinct for only the columns that I want unique values. Or better put, I want the query to pick only one copy of a pipeline run even if it was run multiple times.

```
ADFActivityRun
| where ActivityType == "Copy" or ActivityType == "ExecuteDataFlow"
| where Status == "Succeeded" or Status == "Failed"
| project TimeGenerated, DataFactory=substring(tostring(split(ResourceId, "/", 8)), 2, strlen(tostring(split(ResourceId, "/", 8)))-4), PipelineRunId, PipelineName, ActivityName, Status, ActivityType, Start, End, ErrorMessage, FailureType, RowsRead  = parse_json(Output).rowsRead, RowsCopied = parse_json(Output).rowsCopied, rowsWritten = parse_json(Output).runStatus.metrics.sink1.rowsWritten |order by TimeGenerated desc 
| distinct PipelineName, PipelineRunId, ActivityName, Status, ActivityType, DataFactory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `take_any()` for any, or `arg_max()` for latest:

for example:

```
ADFActivityRun
| where ActivityType in ("Copy", "ExecuteDataFlow")
| where Status in ("Succeeded", "Failed")
| extend Output = parse_json(Output)
| project TimeGenerated, 
          DataFactory = substring(tostring(split(ResourceId, "/", 8)), 2, strlen(tostring(split(ResourceId, "/", 8)))-4),
          PipelineRunId,
          PipelineName,
          ActivityName,
          Status,
          ActivityType,
          Start,
          End,
          ErrorMessage,
          FailureType,
          RowsRead = Output.rowsRead,
          RowsCopied = Output.rowsCopied,
          rowsWritten = Output.runStatus.metrics.sink1.rowsWritten
| summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, *) by PipelineRunId
```

Comment: Thank you good sir, this worked for me and also thankyou for helping to refactor my code.